# Difficulty installing Benzinga API from inside Syder using pip

Tags: python, github, pip, spyder

This question is a bit different other posts because it involves doing the install inside Spyder using PIP. The previous posts do not refer to Spyder or PIP

I'm trying to install the Benzinga library from github inside Spyder. I'm trying to follow the instructions posted here:  https://github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python-client#your-key

I get the following error messages (pip command used is shown as well). Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
 pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python-client.git
 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
 Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python-client.git
 Cloning ssh://****@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python-client.git to 
 c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-i8fkiqdp
 Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
 Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 
 'ssh://****@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python-client.git' 
 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i8fkiqdp'
  Host key verification failed.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

   git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python- 
client.git' 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i8fkiqdp' did not run 
 successfully.
   exit code: 128

   See above for output.

   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com/Benzinga/benzinga-python- 
client.git' 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i8fkiqdp' did not run 
 successfully.
 exit code: 128

 See above for output.

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed